# Is it possible to overlay an icon on top of a geometry object in Open Street Map?

Tags: eclipse, gwt, openlayers, openstreetmap, gwt-openlayers

I was wondering if it was possible to overlay an icon marker over a geometry object in Open Street Maps. I am using gwt-openlayers which is a java wrapped version of the open layers api with an Open Street Map tile server in Eclipse. If anyone has any knowledge about this I'd greatly appreciate it.

Thanks,

Matt

Comment: What type of geometry object are they? (points, polygons, etc)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have it figured out. I am just making two different layers, one for the markers and one for the geometry figures. I am overlaying the markers over the geometry figures by adding the markers to the top of the layer list.

Comment: I'm just trying to add a marker layer.  Could you show a simple example if I post a question on here?

Answer (score 2):

You can if these geometric objects are points by using the [externalGraphic](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Symbolizer/Point-js.html#OpenLayers.Symbolizer.Point.externalGraphic) property which is a URL of the image.

If you need to overlay them on top of a polygon just create an [ImageOverlay](http://dev.openlayers.org/releases/OpenLayers-2.10/doc/apidocs/files/OpenLayers/Layer/Image-js.html#OpenLayers.Layer.Image.OpenLayers.Layer.Image) on top of the center of the polygon.